# Is this a good way to remove Script, Onmouseover,onerror and onload with php

Tags: php, xss

I am doing this. It seems to work but is it best way? Like could people still post XSS code or should this catch it all?

```
$pattern[0] = '/script/'; 
$pattern[1] = '/onmouseover/'; 
$pattern[2] = '/onerror/';
$pattern[3] = '/onload/';
$replacement[0] = 'scr<b></b>ipt'; 
$replacement[1] = 'onmouse<b></b>over'; 
$replacement[2] = 'on<b></b>error'; 
$replacement[2] = 'on<b></b>load';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sanitize user-generated HTML content, I would rather rely on the services of an existing, actively maintained library like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/):

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant HTML filter library written in PHP. HTML Purifier will not only remove all malicious code (better known as XSS) with a thoroughly audited, secure yet permissive whitelist, it will also make sure your documents are standards compliant, something only achievable with a comprehensive knowledge of W3C's specifications.

Comment: The only problem is that this is a heavy wheigt library and if you want to configure it to only allow javascript insertion like in the question it will take hours.....

Comment: Sure - but it's arguably still better than building your own solution in most cases. (That said, if you discover something easier to use, definitely post an answer here!)